# Unable to integrate Factory Pattern along with Spring-Swagger

Tags: spring-mvc, dependency-injection, autowired, swagger-ui, springfox

I have implemented factory pattern using ServiceLocatorFactoryBean by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33993063/annotation-based-servicelocatorfactorybean) reference.

It is working fine.

I am using swagger-springMVC ([SpringFox](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/)), It is also working fine.

But, when I am trying to use factory pattern along with swagger then It is throwing below exceptions,

```
Could not autowire field: org.test.MyProject.MyFactory org.test.MyProject.controller.MyController.myFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.test.MyProject.MyFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
```

I have tried in all possible ways by following several resources but unable to find a solution. Can anyone please help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you please post the code you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a proper root path in your ComponentScan path.  I have faced same kind of issue; after I fixed the ComponentScan path, it is working now as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried removing `@componentScan` but still didn't work. Do we need to add `@componentScan` along with `@Configuration`?

Comment: @Karthik - Don't remove componentScan, provide proper root path.

Comment: Thank you its working after adding the `@componentScan` along the root path. May be it will scan for controllers inbuilt.