# Autowiring in concrete classes of an abstract class than implements an interface

Tags: java, spring-boot, interface, abstract-class, autowired

I am using Spring boot and I have the following Task model

```
public class Task {
    private String name;
    private TaskType type; // ManualTask, AutomatedTask
    private boolean completed;
    //....other fields

    //getters and setters
}
```

A controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/task")
public class TaskController {

    @Autowired
    private TaskService taskService;

    @GetMapping("/{taskId}/handle")
    public String handle(Model model, @PathVariable("taskId") Long taskId) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        try {
            Task task = taskService.handle(taskId);
            model.addAttribute("task", task);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "errorpage";
        }
        return "successpage";
    }
}
```

I have an interface

```
public interface TaskService {

    Task findById(Long taskId);

    Task handleTask(Long taskId) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException;

}
```

An abstract class implements the interface:

```
@Service
public abstract class TaskServiceImpl implements TaskService {

    @Autowired
    private TaskRepository taskRepository;

    private static final String PATH_OF_CLASS = "com.task.service.impl";

    protected abstract Task doTypeSpecificTask(Long taskId);

    @Override
    public Task findById(Long taskId) {
        return taskRepository.findById(taskId).get();
    }

    @Override
    public Task handleTask(Long taskId) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        Task task = findById(taskId);
        TaskServiceImpl service = getHandlerService(task);
        return service.doTypeSpecificTask(taskId);
    }

    private TaskServiceImpl getHandlerService(Task task) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        String serviceClassName = PATH_OF_CLASS.concat(".").concat(task.getTaskType().getName()).concat("Service");
        Class<?> serviceClass = Class.forName(serviceClassName);
        if (!TaskServiceImpl.class.isAssignableFrom(serviceClass)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Service class " + serviceClassName + " did not implements " + TaskServiceImpl.class.getName());
        }
        Object serviceObject = serviceClass.newInstance();
        TaskServiceImpl service = (TaskServiceImpl) serviceObject;
        return service;
    }


}
```

And concrete services that extend the abstract class

```
@Service
@Primary
public class ManualTaskService extends TaskServiceImpl {

    @Autowired
    private TaskRepository taskRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ManualTaskHandlerService manualTaskHandlerService;

    @Override
    protected Task doTypeSpecificTask(Long taskId) {
        Task task = findById(taskId);
        manualTaskHandlerService.handleManualTask(task);
        task.setCompleted(true);
        return taskRepository.save(task);
    }
}

@Service
public class AutomatedTaskService extends TaskServiceImpl {

    @Autowired
    private TaskRepository taskRepository;

    @Autowired
    private AutomatedTaskHandlerService automatedTaskHandlerService;

    @Override
    protected Task doTypeSpecificTask(Long taskId) {
        Task task = findById(taskId);
        automatedTaskHandlerService.handleAutomatedTask(task);
        task.setCompleted(true);
        return taskRepository.save(task);
    }
}

public interface TaskRepository extends JpaRepository<Task, Long> {

}
```

The `ManualTaskService` or `AutomatedTaskService` is selected dynamically based on the type of task on runtime.

Now, without the `@Primary`, I get the following error:

```
Field taskService in com.test.controller.TaskController required a single bean, but 2 were found:
- manualTaskService
- automatedTaskService

Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

With `@Primary` set in ManualTaskService, `doTypeSpecificTask` in ManualTaskService works but in AutomatedTaskService it fails because of `automatedTaskHandlerService.handleAutomatedTask(task)`. Also calls to taskRepository from AutomatedTaskService fail.

I've tried using `@Qualifier` as well as defining all `@Autowired` in the abstract class as protected but nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is some weird looking class hierarchy.

Comment: @EugenCovaci Could you please let me know or point me to some resources from which this could be made better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by using the factory pattern as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390810/implement-a-simple-factory-pattern-with-spring-3-annotations) link (thanks to @user7294900 for providing the link)

I completely removed the abstract class `TaskServiceImpl`. Instead I created two new interfaces `ManualTaskService` and `AutomatedTaskService` both extending `TaskService` interface

```
public interface ManualTaskService extends TaskService {
}

public interface AutomatedTaskService extends TaskService {     
}
```

Then I created a `TaskServiceFactory`

```
@Component
public class TaskServiceFactory {

    @Autowired
    private ManualTaskService manualTaskService;

    @Autowired
    private AutomatedTaskService automatedTaskService;

    public TaskService getService(TaskType type) throws Exception {
        switch (type) {
        case MANUAL_TASK:
            return manualTaskService;
        case AUTOMATED_TASK:
            return automatedTaskService;
        default:
            throw new Exception("Unrecognized task type");
        }
    }
}
```

Next I created implementations for both `ManualTaskService` and `AutomatedTaskService`

```
@Service
public class ManualTaskServiceImpl implements ManualTaskService {

    @Autowired
    private TaskRepository taskRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ManualTaskHandlerService manualTaskHandlerService;

    @Override
    public Task findById(Long taskId) {
        return taskRepository.findById(taskId).get();
    }

    @Override
    public Task handleTask(Long taskId) throws Exception {
        Task task = findById(taskId);
        manualTaskHandlerService.handleManualTask(task);
        task.setCompleted(true);
        return taskRepository.save(task);
    }
}


@Service
public class AutomatedTaskServiceImpl implements AutomatedTaskService {

    @Autowired
    private TaskRepository taskRepository;

    @Autowired
    private AutomatedTaskHandlerService automatedTaskHandlerService;

    @Override
    public Task findById(Long taskId) {
        return taskRepository.findById(taskId).get();
    }

    @Override
    public Task handleTask(Long taskId) throws Exception {
        Task task = findById(taskId);
        automatedTaskHandlerService.handleAutomatedTask(task);
        task.setCompleted(true);
        return taskRepository.save(task);
    }

}
```

Finally I updated the controller to get the task type from the user and then use the `TaskServiceFactory` to get the correct service instance based on the type

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/task")
public class TaskController {

    @Autowired
    private TaskServiceFactory taskServiceFactory;

    @PostMapping("/{taskId}/handle")
    public String handle(Model model, @PathVariable("taskId") Long taskId, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        try {
            TaskType type = TaskType.valueOf(request.getParameter("type"));
            Task task = taskServiceFactory.getService(type).handleTask(taskId, request);
            model.addAttribute("task", task);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "errorpage";
        }
        return "successpage";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have different names to each Qualifier:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("manualTaskService")
private TaskServiceImpl manualTaskService;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("automatedTaskService")
private TaskServiceImpl automatedTaskService;
```

Which is defined in services:

```
@Service("manualTaskService")
public class ManualTaskService extends TaskServiceImpl {

@Service("automatedTaskService")
public class AutomatedTaskService extends TaskServiceImpl {
```

Comment: Should I define the `@Qualifiers` in the controller? If so, how do I define `Task task = taskService.handle(taskId);` in the controller? because I don't know what type of task it is unless it gets resolved by the taskService.

Comment: It is dynamic based on what the user selects and is resolved at runtime.

Comment: @KshitijBajracharya add logic and use relevant service (autowire both and use when needed)

Comment: This was just simplified to show two implementations, I have multiple implementations of the service. Could you please point me to some examples where autowiring multiple concrete classes is done when the class is dynamically retrieved?

Comment: @KshitijBajracharya example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390810/implement-a-simple-factory-pattern-with-spring-3-annotations

Comment: Your original answer didn't solve my problem but it did provide me with helpful pointers, especially the latter link that you provided. I have now solved my problem. +1 for all your support :)