# Implementation of Factory design, faced this error in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, factory, factory-pattern

Hi I have created a factory, with the help of some guidance from @DruidKuma from the link : [Implement a simple factory pattern with Spring 3 annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390810/implement-a-simple-factory-pattern-with-spring-3-annotations)

I created the factory as follows:

```
@Component
public class ValidatorFactory {
    @Autowired
    private List<Validator> validators;

    private static final Map<String, Validator> validatorMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void setValidatorMap() {
        for (Validator validator : validators) {
            validatorMap.putIfAbsent(validator.getCountry().name(), validator);
        }
    }

    public Validator getValidator(Value v) {
        return validatorMap.get(v.name());
    }
}
```

But when I am trying to start the application I am getting this error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field validators in com.abc.factory.ValidatorFactory required a bean of type 'java.util.List' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'java.util.List' in your configuration.
```

What I understood from the link which helped me was that spring should create the bean automatically.
Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

As per your code:

```
@Autowired
private List<Validator> validators;
```

Spring tries to find beans of type `Validator`, if it does not find any bean then it throws the error `required a bean of type 'java.util.List' that could not be found.`

To fix the issue, make sure that you have beans of type `Validator` in classpath and they are being scanned by spring container, for example using `@ComponentScan`.

Comment: The `Validator` bean is present and the classpath for the project is provided in the Application file. But I am still getting the error.

Comment: @NBorah, can you add more details to your post, your bean details and spring configuration file etc.

Comment: I had made a minor mistake, did not declare component for the Validator implementation. Its fixed and working as expected.